# Could Someone Please Verify My Proof? (fun with two primes)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Am I wrong? Is my proof clear?
<strike>Is this already a known result?</strike> If so, are there any simple implications or corollaries of this proof? (if that makes sense) I know some about groups, rings and fields, but not enough to argue with them.

Suppose $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n=2k$, and $k>2$.
$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x+y=k-1$.
I claim that if $2x+1$ and $2y+1$ are prime then $n$ is the sum of two primes.

$$\begin{align*}
n&=2k,\\  
&=2(x+y+1),\\  
&=4xy+2(x+y+1)-4xy,\\  
&=4xy+2x+2y+2-4xy,\\  
&=(4xy+2x+2y+1)+1-4xy,\\  
&=(4xy+2x+2y+1)+1-((2x+1)-1)((2y+1)-1),\\  
&=(2x+1)(2y+1)+1-((2x+1)-1)((2y+1)-1).
\end{align*}$$

Let $m,l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m=2x+1$ and $l=2y+1$.

Then $$n=ml+1-(m-1)(l-1)$$ and

$  
\forall p_{1},p_{2}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{1}$ and   $p_{2}$ are prime, if
$m=p_{1}$ and $l=p_{2}$
$$\begin{align*}
n&=2k,\\
&=ml+1-(m-1)(l-1),\\
&=p_{1}p_{2}+1-(p_{1}-1)(p_{2}-1),\\
&\therefore n=p_{1}+p_{2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Proof of *what*?

Comment: The question shows some effort even if the result turned out to be trivial so I don't think downvotes are warranted.

Comment: lol and thank you. I admit I don't really know what I'm talking about and that I am basically repeating myself. It seems like the way I arrived at the result is worth looking at though. I just wondered if anyone knew of any methods of proof that somehow utilized this, or about any results that seemed apparent from looking at the sum of two primes this way

Comment: I'm asking more if anyone could expound some about the specific criteria I start with (n=2k, x+y=k−1) and the way I arrived at that trivial conclusion than I am about the fact.

Comment: "I just wondered if anyone knew of any methods of proof that somehow utilized this" You mean algebraic manipulation? If so then it has been utilized extensively.

Comment: "it has been utilized extensively" That makes sense. I guess then I'm asking about the specific algebraic manipulation I used. I think the fact that I can manipulate my way from n=2k to 2k=ml+1−(m−1)(l−1) is interesting, and I wonder what conclusions might result from being able to do that.

Comment: That's a roundabout derivation of $\ 2(x+y+1) = 2x\!+\!1\,+\, 2y\!+\!1\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the result is quite trivial:
$$x+y=k−1$$
$$2x+2y=2k-2=n-2$$
$$(2x+1)+(2y+1)=n$$
So if $2x+1$ and $2y+1$ are prime then $n$ is the sum of two primes.

Comment: "I'm afraid the result is quite trivial" yeah, but in a weird way. I'm asking more if anyone could expound some about the specific criteria I start with (n=2k, x+y=k−1) and the way I arrived at that trivial conclusion than I am about the fact.

Comment: What is there to say about starting with something simple and then finding a complicated way to do something simple with it?

Comment: "What is there to say about starting with something simple and then finding a complicated way to do something simple with it?" Isn't the whole idea of Abstract Algebra to start with something simple and find a complicated way to do something else simple with it?

Comment: Let me know, Matt, when you have found a simple way to prove that there's no formula for solving fifth degree equations in radicals.